# Validation of Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, validation, finance

As data analytics and machine-learning approaches become more and more integrated, proper validation of such models also gain traction. **Since validation of models are a necessity in many industries such as banking and finance, and are used extensively for traditional credit/market risk models, the question becomes how to effectively validate ANN models?**

For instance, assuming a neural network can actually achieve a reasonable performance confirmed through the validation set, **How can one demonstrate and make the case that the hyper parameters chosen are indeed 'close-to-optimal' parameters?**

hyper parameters such as number of hidden layers, number of neurons per layer, drop out rate, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by close-to-optimal?  It's hard to conceptualize a model like that as somehow estimating the truth, so it seems best to me to evaluate the model on the basis of it's usefulness in solving the problem it is intended to solve.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that since you can in theory have infinite number of different combinations for your hyper-param., and your resources don't really allow you to try every possible combination, how do you ensure your model is indeed reasonable? Thus far, my model has been inspired by relevant literature with some minor tweeks to enhance performance. If passed down to validation, they will dissect the architecture and attempt to establish a benchmark model to beat this model (i.e. accuracy). So in essence, how can I in a systematic way ensure that my model is as 'accurate' as it can be?

Comment: In principle there's no way of figuring out if your chosen hyperparameters are truly optimal, except through cross validation. This becomes insanely expensive, especially for neural networks and rarely gives substantial increases in performance. Rather than spending most your time meddling with hyperparameters, instead look for ways to improve your features or try different models that might be more suitable for the problem at hand.

Comment: You may have somewhat answered your own question. The best you can do is try your model on data you haven't used yet and see if the results are good enough.

Comment: @MatthewDrury - From a mathematical standpoint "close-to-optimal" means the global optimum of an optimisation problem, which implies having the lowest possible error, albeit not zero error (i.e. the "truth"). Anyway, this question is too abstract, entire books have been written to treat this topic.